# How to allow responding to broadcast pings on Mikrotik RouterOS?

Tags: ping, mikrotik, icmp, routeros

By default, [most systems don't respond to broadcast ping requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855358/problem-with-pinging-broadcast-address). However, [there exist ways to explicitly allow responding to broadcast ICMP requests on multiple systems, such as Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7458/cant-ping-broadcast).

How can I enable responding to broadcast ping requests on Mikrotik?

Using `/tool sniffer start` and `/tool sniffer packet print` I was able to verify that the broadcast packets do indeed reach the Mikrotik routers, but a response is never sent.